# Trying to combine select & Update

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2016

I have a select statement where i get some records based upon a condition

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Status = 3
from dbo.Table A
JOIN (Select fkID, count(1) as total
        from dbo.TableLogs A
        Group by fkID
        having count(1) > 10) B
  on B.fkID = A.id
Where A.status = 2

select status,id,filename from table 
where status not in (1,3)
```

i want to merge those both queries in one single statement that if the files which had total count of more than 10, update status to 3 and continue filtering files to get only those files which has status of neither `1` or `3`

Comment: It is not clear what you would like to achieve. Do you like to create a stored procedure?

Comment: Why does it need to happen in a single command? I ask because there is no update and select command.

Comment: `Update` will update rows, but not return any. `Select` will return rows, but not update any. If you want to update AND return rows, you will need two commands.

Comment: i need a kind of stored procedure which will do both things, first it will verify and then if the count is more than 10, it will update, and lastly, it will do a select to return me the query data, the select should be able to accept parameters if i want to add new filters to it

Comment: A stored procedure will allow you to do exactly that: sequential logical steps with predictable results. Parameters and code can always be added and updated. Not sure where that leaves us on this question.

Comment: And are you really using 2008? The end of life of that product is less than 2 months away. Time to consider upgrading.

Comment: nopes, i am using 2016

Comment: It is the same table in both statements?

Comment: in select and update -yes, different for logs

Comment: It seems to me that both statements should execute always. It means one statement ( UPDATE ) does not exclude other statement ( SELECT )?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't linking the tables correctly. I'm not sure the exact query you want to run from your question, but, try starting with this:

```
UPDATE A
SET A.Status = 3
FROM A, (Select fkID, count(1) as total
        from dbo.TableLogs A
        Group by fkID
        having count(1) > 10) AS B
WHERE B.[fkID] = A.[id]
AND A.status = 2
;
```

You can add more where statements to the bottom of the code.

Cheers,